# How to display an ACF checkbox value in MPDF?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, mpdf

I have been working with mpdf and acf to generate a pdf. I can generate the pdf and display text values but I can't get it to display the values of a checkbox, it displays nothing.

This is the code that I have, what am I doing wrong? How do I get it to display something for the checkbox?

$offer is the checkbox that I am trying to display.

```
add_action('init', 'congres_redirect');

function congres_redirect() {

  if(isset($_GET['offer'])) {
   global $post; //ADD THIS
$offerid = $_GET['offer'];
    $restname = get_field('restaurant_name', $offerid);

    $offer = get_field_object('restaurant_offer', $offerid);

    if( in_array( '2courses10', $offer ) or '2courses10' == $offer ) { $offer2for10='2 courses for 10'; }



    $randNum = strtoupper(generateRandomString(5));
    $date = date("Ymd");
    $namecode = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $restname));
    $namestr = substr($namecode, 0, 6);

    view_conferinta($restname, $randNum, $date, $namecode, $namestr);
  }
}

function view_conferinta($restname, $randNum, $date, $namecode, $namestr) {
global $post;


$output = '<html>
<head><title>'.$restname.' | Eat Leeds</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>

<body style="font-family:chelvetica;">

 <table class="voucher-content" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="60%"></td>
      <td width="40%">
        <table>
        <tr class="inner-voucher">
            <td class="offer-details" style="color: #fff !important;">'.$restname.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inner-voucher">
            <td class="offer-details" style="color: #fff !important;">'.$offer2for10.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 280px; color: #fff;"><div class="vouchercode">Voucher Code: EL-'.$namestr.''.$date.'-'.$randNum.'</div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>




</table>


</body>
</html>';


require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';


$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
$mpdf->Output('eatleeds-EL-'.$namestr.''.$date.'-'.$randNum.'.pdf','I');
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not set a default value for **$offer2for10**.

You could also use a switch and loop into $offer value:

```php
switch ($offer) {
  case '2courses10':
    $offer2for10 = "2 courses for 10";
    break;
  
  default:
    $offer2for10 = "Unknown offer";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this still doesn't work. I have added in the code like this:


    $offer = get_field_object('restaurant_offer', $offerid);
    switch ($offer) {
      case '2courses10':
        $offer2for10 = "2 courses for 10";
        break;

      default:
        $offer2for10 = "Unknown offer";
        break;
    }

<td class="offer-details" style="color: #fff !important;"><h2>'.$offer2for10.'</h2></td>

but it doesn't output anything.

Comment: You should write tests on your code to find the bug. And please note that you’ve set the table-data tag’s color to #fff which is a white color code, it maybe does output something but you cannot see it.